# Use random name generator after getting input from keyboard

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package username;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class UserName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
       
        String user_Name1;
        System.out.print("Please enter the first username: ");
        user_Name1 = input.nextLine();
            if (user_Name1.equals("")) {
                String[] randoms = {"Luke", "Leia", "Sophia", "David"};
                name = randoms[((int) Math.random()*randoms.length)];
            }
            
            System.out.println("" + user_Name1);
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your question? This way it will probably be removed soon...

Comment: You need to add an actual question to your post. Preferably with an example input, current output, and expected output

Comment: @Cedced_Bro is it ok if you could please break down this code line and explain it further?:

user_Name1 = randoms[(int) (Math.random() * randoms.length)];

Comment: Btw. For the next questions you post on StackOverflow you keep the original question and don't insert the answer into your code. This helps others who might have the same problem to understand it and benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
// Starting in main function after the System.out.println()

String name = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close(); // optional but recommended

if (name == null || name.equals("") {
    // Do random pick as you did before and assign it to name
    String[] randoms = {"Luke", "Leia", "Sophia", "David"}; // Add all names here
    name = randoms[((int) Math.random()*randoms.length)]; // Pick random name
}

System.out.println("Your name is " + name);

// The rest of the class with closing brackets
```

Comment: That is great thank you so much! The only thing that is happening is that it is only comping back with Luke and not any of the other names on the list?

Comment: Scratch that- fixed. Thanks heaps Cedced_Bro! To be honest i'm trying to understand the following lines of code: 

String[] randoms = {"Luke", "Leia", "Hans", "R2D2"};
                user_Name1 = randoms[(int) (Math.random() * randoms.length)];

Comment: String[] randoms = {"Luke", "Leia", "Sophia", "David"}; creates a String Array with the Elements Luke, Leia, Sophia and David. The size of it depends on how many inputs you give in this case 4 then. This is much quicker than manually creating an empty Array and then adding the names manually into the array like you did earlier. The following line is also just shortening your code. It picks a name randomly out of the created array. This is done by calling Math.random() as you did before but to make it modular I wasn't multiplying it by a fixed amount but by the arrays length with randoms.length